# Using nltk inside Django app

Tags: python, django, web-applications, nlp, nltk

I am trying to use NLTK within a Django app that I'm creating and don't know how to go about achieving this. I have functions written in .py files, and want to use them inside my web app. How exactly can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Import the code for your nltk functions into your django code; either copy and paste it, or just do a import statement for them.

Comment: @benjamin When I try to import nltk at the top of my views.py it always returns "no module named nltk" error.

Comment: @jblew, how did you install NLTK?

Comment: Create a virtualenv, activate the virtualenv and then run `pip install nltk`. As a good practice, never start django projects without using a virtual environment. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: This is a django / python problem, and the solution would be the same for any other non-standard python module. @alvas, I think you should expand your comment into an answer (or possibly find and flag a duplicate :-)).

Comment: @Chris I have the standard NLTK corpus installed on my computer via terminal from http://www.nltk.org/install.html .

Comment: @jblew, alvas' suggestion is almost certainly the right one.

Comment: @alvas Okay, I installed nltk inside my virtualenv into my project folder, from here can I use `import nltk` in my files?

Comment: @Chris I followed what he said and am still getting "no module named nltk" error in my terminal when running my server.

Comment: @jblew, your Django app needs to use the same virtualenv. Have you activated it?

Comment: @Chris Yes my env is activated and with my Django app, it is working now. I am able to "import nltk" in the top of my views.py file successfully, but do you know how I can use functions written with nltk inside Django now that it is working?

Comment: @jblew, see the very first comment here from benjamin.

Answer (score 3):

so lets say you want to classify a user's name as female or male, you could do the following in your view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import names
import random
```

then we take the post request, that contains the name, exactly the way you do it with forms

```
def index(request):
message = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    input_name = request.POST.get("name", "")

    if input_name != '':
```

then prepare the labels for every gender and shuffle them

```
labeled_names = ([(name, 'male') for name in names.words('male.txt')] + [(name, 'female') for name in names.words('female.txt')])
 random.shuffle(labeled_names)
```

Now create the training/testing sets

```
 train_set = feature_set[:3000] 
 test_set = feature_set[3000:]
```

then the NaivesBayes classifier

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

so to make the prediction we need to pass the input_name to the classifier and return the message

```
message = input_name + " is probably " + classifier.classify(gender_features(input_name))
```

Finaly we return the context and the message to the template

```
context = {'message': message}
return render(request, 'Myapp/template.html', context)
```

Comment: Won't this be time-consuming as the model is training each time you are loading a page?